# Fastest way to set button event

Tags: c#, java, android, button, lambda

I'm building an android app for the first time using java. (I am used to Xamarin with C#)

In C#, when you set a button and subscribe to it's click event, you can simply use a lambda and do this :

```
myButton.Click += (s,e) => { DoSomething();};
```

But in Java, it seems like the fastest way to go is like this :

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

        DoSomething();

        }
     });
```

Since I will work a lot with buttons and events, I want to know if there is a faster way to do it in Java. Something closer to what I do in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do something similar to what you have in C# but if you have more buttons you can make your activity implement `OnClickListener` and override its onClick method. Call `myButton.setOnClickListener(this)` for every button in Activity. Now click event of all your buttons will be handled by one method in which you can check which button make the call and do appropiate actions

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:onClick` listener in xml and then write a simple funcation that return a void and get a view:

```
public void onclick(View view) {

    }
```

Comment: Nice seems way faster like this. I will try.

Comment: Yes I think I got that by now.

Comment: @phadaphunk I think forgot ;)